# VBA - code only loops through the first worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Learning VBA and doing a challenge for a course, am having trouble looping the following code through all the worksheets in a workbook. The code seems to perfectly for the first sheet (sheets are titled 'A', 'B' and so forth to 'F') but the loops ends after the first sheet? However the headers print just fine (ws.Range.("I9") - ws.Range("L1") in the code below) across all the sheets but just not the data below it unlike the first sheet. Here is the code:

```
Sub Challenge()

Dim Ticker As String
Dim VolStock As Double
VolStock = 0

Dim PCounter As Double
PCounter = 2

Dim Info As Double
Info = 2

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    Dim OpenPrice As Double
    Dim ClosePrice As Double
    Dim YChange As Double
    Dim PChange As Double
    


    
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If ws.Range("A" & i + 1).Value <> ws.Range("A" & i).Value Then
            Ticker = ws.Range("A" & i).Value
            ws.Range("I" & Info).Value = Ticker
            
            VolStock = VolStock + ws.Cells(i, 7).Value
            ws.Range("L" & Info).Value = VolStock
            ws.Range("L" & Info).NumberFormat = "0"
            
            OpenPrice = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
            ClosePrice = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
            
            YChange = ClosePrice - OpenPrice
            PChange = YChange / OpenPrice
            
            ws.Range("J" & Info) = YChange
            ws.Range("K" & Info) = PChange
            ws.Range("K" & Info).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
            
            ws.Range("I1").Value = "Ticker"
            ws.Range("J1").Value = "Yearly Change"
            ws.Range("K1").Value = "Percent Change"
            ws.Range("L1").Value = "Total Stock Volume"
            
                If ws.Range("J" & Info) >= 0 Then
                    ws.Range("J" & Info).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                Else
                    ws.Range("J" & Info).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
        
            VolStock = 0
            PCounter = i + 1
            Info = Info + 1
        Else
            VolStock = VolStock + ws.Cells(i, 7).Value
        End If
        
    
   
    
    Next i
        
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: The code is looping through all sheets, otherwise the headers wouldn't get printed across all of them. What does `Debug.Print lastrow` return for each sheet? Should `PCounter` and `Info` get "reset" for each sheet? i.e., should `PCounter =2` and `Info = 2` be inside the loop?

Comment: @BigBen Ah yes you're right. Debug.Print lastrow doesn return anything and they should be reset for each sheet.

Comment: @aqguapo In the line where you get the _lastrow_ `Rows.Count` refers to the active sheet.

Comment: @Shrotter Thank you both, after trying both your solutions it worked! Have a great day!